# Lists and Member Implementation in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm just starting to learn Common Lisp and the text I'm reading uses an example with the `member` function.

I'm unsure of the distinction between these two blocks of code:

```
(if (member nil '(1 nil 2 3))
    'contains-nil
    'does-not-contain-nil)
```

returns CONTAINS_NIL

```
(if (member nil '(1 2 3))
    'contains-nil
    'does-not-contain-nil)
```

returns DOES-NOT-CONTAIN-NIL

From what I understand, lists are equivalent to nested `cons` cells, so I would think `(member nil (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))` would return `(nil)`, but it just returns `nil`.  I'm not sure how a compiler or interpreter would make that distinction, and if someone could give me some insight on how I could implement the `member` function, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cons cell holds two values, typically called its `car` and its `cdr`.  The expression `(cons x y)` returns a cons cell whose `car` is `x`, and whose `cdr` is `y`.  In Lisp, a *list* is either the empty list (typically the symbol `nil`), or a cons cell.  When a list is a cons cell, the *first* element of the list is the cons cell's `car`, and the *rest* of the list is the cons cell's `cdr`.  Consider the list `(1 2 3)`.  It is a cons cell, and the first element of the list is `1`.  The rest of the list is not empty, so it must be another list whose first element is `2`.  The rest of that list is not empty, so it must be another list whose first element is `3`.  The rest of that list *is* empty, i.e., `nil`.  Based on that analysis, we can see why the list is formed by

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))
== (1 2 3)
```

In a chain of cons cells that make up a list, the elements of the list are the *car* values of each cons cell in the chain.  Lists can be elements of lists, as in

```
(cons 1 (cons nil (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))))
== (1 nil 2 3)
```

or

```
(cons 1 (cons (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)) nil))
== (1 (2 3))
```

but just because we see `nil` in the longer expression doesn't mean that `nil` is an element of the list.

Comment: So to implement this in an interpreter, you would have some thing similar to `(if (equal (cdr list) nil) 'list-over 'list-not-over))`

Comment: If `list-over` means "the rest of this list is empty," then yes.  Common Lisp provides the function [endp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_endp.htm) for this purpose, of course:  `(endp nil) => t`, and `(endp nil) => nil`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor There's a typo in that last comment.  The second code example should be, e.g., `(endp '(1 . 2)) => nil`.

Answer (score 2):

`MEMBER` looks only at the elements of the list, not the list itself. An empty list is something different than an empty list with another empty list as an element.

`()` is not the same as `(())`. `()` is not the same as `(nil)`.

Since a list is made of cons cells, the elements are the `cars` of the cons cells.

Answer (score 1):

A list is defined to be either the empty list NIL or to be a cons cell whose CAR is an element of the list and whose CDR is another list.
The list that is produced by

```
(cons 1 nil)
```

is a list that has the element 1 and also all the elements of the empty list. The empty list has no elements, so NIL is not an element of the list.
It is similar with sets: Although the empty set is a subset of any set it is not an element of every set (while it isn't generally prohibited from being an element of a set).

One way o implement MEMBER is like this:

```
(defun member (item list)
  (if list
      (if (eql item (car list))
          list
          (member item (cdr list)))))
```

So if LIST is NIL the whole function will return NIL.

Comment: There is no reason for the empty set to be an element of another set, just like the empty list `nil` may be an element of another list.

It should rather read: Although the empty set is a subset of every set, it is not an element of every set (but might be of some).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have no idea why I wrote it the way I did.

Answer (score -1):

Our own version of the predefined member function in lisp can be defined as :

```
(defun member2 (item lst)
  (if lst
      (if (eql item (car lst))
          T
          (member2 item (cdr lst)))))
```