# Writing a function to search for matches in lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to make a function that will return true if it finds a match for an item in another list. But it seems like everything should work, but on a call (f1 '(2) '(1 2 3)) return nil

```
(defun f1 (x y)
 (cond 
  ((null y) x)
  ((equalp x (car y))
  (t (f1 x (cdr y))))))
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement `member`? Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684654/13590263](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684654/13590263)

Comment: I doubt it returns NIL for your example with the code you wrote here

Comment: coredump, after calling the function, NIL is output in the next line

Comment: Martin Půda, it is necessary to implement manually, and not take a ready-made function

Comment: @Russian_Noname sorry, the indentation was tricky the code never reaches the part where it calls function X on (cdr y), the `cond` is malformed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code after I auto-format it in Emacs is as follows:

```
(defun f1 (x y)
  (cond
   ((equalp x(car y))
    (t(f1(x (cdr y)))))))
```

There is one clause in the `cond`, so the part that starts with `(t ...)` is in fact a call to function `t` (which does not exist). Also, you are calling `f1` with `(x (cdr y))` but `x` is not a function either.

You are also comparing `x` with `(car y)`, but in your test you pass two lists as arguments:

```
(f1 '(2) '(1 2 3))
```

I think you should first write an auxiliary function `belongs-to`, which finds if some `value` exists in a `list`:

```
(defun belongs-to (value list)
  "Returns non-NIL if VALUE is found in LIST using EQUALP"
  (cond
    ;; empty list
    (... NIL)
    ;; general case - match head of list
    (... T)
    ;; general case - recurse on tail of list
    (T (belongs-to ... ...))))
```

Once you have this function, you can use it in `f0`:

```
(defun f0 (x y)
  (and x (or (belongs-to ... ...)
             (f0 ... y))))
```

Comment: I didn't quite get it. I have 2 lists, but in X there is always 1 character, and in Y there are several. I run cond, which compares the list X, where there is 1 element, with the head Y, that is, also with 1 element. And if they are not equal, that is, NIL, then goes to the T block and is recursively called. If 1 condition is not enough in cond, you can add a check for the emptiness of x and y (I did, the function did not work correctly).  But I still can't figure out what's wrong with this function.   so that it returns true if there is an item in this list and NIL if not

Comment: Ok but the T block is never called, the cond is not written properly: the syntax is `(COND C1 C2 ... CN)` where each `Ci` is a list `(TEST . BODY)` (where the body can be empty). Here your first clause has this test: `(equalp x (car y))`, and the body contains `(T ...)` so you need to move the parentheses to fix that. Secondly, if you call `(CAR Y)` where Y is a list like `(1 2 3)` then you will obtain `1`, not `(1)`, so the test can never work if both `X` and `Y` are list of numbers/characters. (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm)

Comment: OK, I figured out how to fix the equal problem. To check, I created a function (defun f2(x y)
                                                                                                                 (f1 (car x) y))                           Logically, not (1) is passed to f1, but 1. Therefore, equal will work. But another mistake came out. "attempt to call `T' which is an undefined function." . Now I don't even have any ideas. I changed the code in the question

Comment: Please see the link I added in the last comment, it describes are COND must be written I am pretty sure you are having a minor syntax error that makes the interpreter take `(T ...)` as a call to function T, which is undefined

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right. Thanks a lot